Proof for L'hôpital rule
I'm trying to prove L'Hôpital rule using the definition my textbook presents, my work is as follows.
First, consider the following property, which I'll name Property 1:
Suppose that $h$ is differentiable on the open interval $I=]p,q[$, with $h'(x)>0$ on $I$, and such that $\lim_{x \to p^+}h(x)=0$. In this way, for all $x \in I$, we have $h(x)>0$.
Proof:
Consider the function $K$, defined on $[p,q[$ and given by
$ K(x)= \begin{cases} 
   h(x) & x \in ]p,q[ \\
   0 & x=p
  \end{cases}
$
Since $h$ is differentiable on $I$, then $h$ is continuous on this interval. Therefore, $K$ is also continuous on $I$. On the other hand, $\lim_{x \to p^+}K(x)=\lim_{x \to p^+}h(x)=0=K(0)$, that is, $K$ is continuous on $p=0$. This way, $K$ is continuous on $[p,q[$. For $x \in I$, $K'(x)=h'(x)$, and so $K(x)$ is increasing on $I$, by the median value theorem. Also, $K(p)=0$, and it follows that $K(x)>0$ for all $x \in I$, that is, $h(x)>0$ for all $x \in I$.
Now, my textbook defines L'hôpital rule as the following, for the case $0/0$ and $x \to p^+$.
Let $f$ and $g$ be differentiable functions on $]p,p+r[$, $r>0$, with $g'(x) \neq 0$ for $]p,p+r[$. In this way, if $\lim_{x \to p^+}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x \to p^+}g(x)=0$ and if $\lim_{x \to p^+}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists, then $\lim_{x \to p^+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists and $\lim_{x \to p^+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x \to p^+}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$.
Proof:
Suppose that $\lim_{x \to p^+}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=L$, then given any $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$, with $\delta<r$, such that, for $x \in ]p,p+\delta[$
$L-\epsilon<\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}<L+\epsilon$
$\implies g'(x)(L-\epsilon)-f'(x)<0$ and $g'(x)(L+\epsilon)-f'(x)>0$
From $\lim_{x \to p^+}f(x)=0$ and from $\lim_{x \to p^+}g(x)=0$ we have that $\lim_{x \to p^+}(g(x)(L-\epsilon)-f(x))=0$ and $\lim_{x \to p^+}(g(x)(L+\epsilon)-f(x))=0$.
This way, by property 1, considering $h(x)=g(x)(L-\epsilon)-f(x)$ and $h(x)=g(x)(L+\epsilon)-f(x)$ for the respective limits, we have
$g(x)(L+\epsilon)-f(x)>0 \implies \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}<L+\epsilon$ and
$g(x)(L-\epsilon)-f(x)<0 \implies (L-\epsilon)<\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$
$\implies (L-\epsilon)<\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}<L+\epsilon$
Therefore, $\lim_{x \to p^+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L$.
Now, I've tried to prove the case $x \to p^-$, where I didn't get it.
First, I had to adapt property 1, as follows:
Suppose that $h$ is differentiable on the open interval $I=]q,p[$, with $h'(x)>0$ on I, and such that $\lim_{x \to p^-}h(x)=0$. In this way, for all $x \in I$, we have $h(x)>0$.
Proof:
Consider the function $K$, defined on $]q,p]$ and given by
$ K(x)= \begin{cases}    
h(x) & x \in ]q,p[ \\   
0 & x=p  
\end{cases} 
$
Since $h$ is differentiable on $I$, then $h$ is continuous on this interval. Therefore, $K$ is also continuous on $I$. On the other hand, $\lim_{x \to p^-}K(x)=\lim_{x \to p^-}h(x)=0=K(0)$, that is, $K$ is continuous on $p=0$. This way, $K$ is continuous on $]q,p]$. For $x \in I$, $K'(x)=h'(x)$, and so $K(x)$ is increasing on $I$, by the median value theorem. Also, $K(p)=0$, and it follows that $K(x)<0$ for all $x \in I$ (in this case because, for all $x \in I$, $K(x)<K(0)=0$), that is, $h(x)<0$ for all $x \in I$.
And now, going for the proof for the case $x \to p^-$:
Let $f$ and $g$ be differentiable functions on $]p-r,p[$, $r>0$, with $g'(x) \neq 0$ for $]p-r,p[$. In this way, if $\lim_{x \to p^-}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x \to p^-}g(x)=0$ and if $\lim_{x \to p^-}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists, then $\lim_{x \to p^-}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists and $\lim_{x \to p^-}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x \to p^-}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$.
Proof:
Suppose that $\lim_{x \to p^-}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=L$, then given any $\epsilon>0$, there is
$\delta>0$, with $\delta<r$, such that, for $x \in ]p-\delta,p[$
$L-\epsilon<\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}<L+\epsilon$
$\implies g'(x)(L-\epsilon)-f'(x)<0$ and $g'(x)(L+\epsilon)-f'(x)>0$
From $\lim_{x \to p^-}f(x)=0$ and from $\lim_{x \to p^-}g(x)=0$ we have that $\lim_{x \to p^-}(g(x)(L-\epsilon)-f(x))=0$ and $\lim_{x \to p^-}(g(x)(L+\epsilon)-f(x))=0$.
This way, by the adapted property 1, considering $h(x)=g(x)(L-\epsilon)-f(x)$ and $h(x)=g(x)(L+\epsilon)-f(x)$ for the respective limits, we have
$g(x)(L+\epsilon)-f(x)<0 \implies \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}>L+\epsilon$ and
$g(x)(L-\epsilon)-f(x)>0 \implies (L-\epsilon)>\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$
And so we will have $L+\epsilon<\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}<L-\epsilon$, which is not $\lim_{x \to p^+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L$ in this case.
I think I'm missing some algebraic manipulation or sign changes somewhere, because it's almost there.
I'd appreciate any help to solve this.

Why prove it as a separate thing? Simply note that
$$\lim_{x\uparrow p}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\overset{u=-x}{=}\lim_{u\downarrow-p}\frac{f(-u)}{g(-u)}=\lim_{u\downarrow-p}\frac{-f'(-u)}{-g'(-u)}=\lim_{u\downarrow-p}\frac{f'(-u)}{g'(-u)}\overset{x=-u}{=}\lim_{x\uparrow p}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$
where all we have done is a simple change of variables in the intermediate steps to apply the first version, which is already proven.

It's because in my case it's a very begginer proof, using basically only these calculus tools. For example, I don't know what that "uparrow" in your limit means.

@RuanCarlos $\lim_{x\uparrow p}$ is just another way or writing $\lim_{x\to p^-}$, and similarly $\lim_{x\downarrow p}$ means $\lim_{x\to p^+}$. Is there anything else in my proof you don't follow? Change of variables for limits is usually one of the first things proven

Interesting notation, I get it now. Thanks!!

How is the second step proven here without assuming the required result?

@user3490 op has already proven it for limits from one side, so all I do is use that result to prove that for limits from the other side
